# How to trigger CSS3 fade-in effect using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, fade

I've implemented a fade-in effect using pure Javascript, but I yearn for something more native, like using CSS3. Is there a way to trigger the CSS fade-in effect from Javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

HTML:

```
<div id="foo" class="hidden">Hello!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.hidden {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('foo').className = '';
}, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RYgsA/

Comment: Yay for vendor prefixes! `-o-transition:`

Comment: @AlexWayne Hi AlexWayne, I have the same question but am trying to figure out the next step.  I have tried the jsfiddle code you posted, which works very well, but I am trying to adapt it to work more than once.  I have a div element which I want to fade in every time a certain button is clicked. I tried re-adding the class 'hidden' but can't seem to get it to work more than the first time.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

here you go

HTML

```
<div id="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
#box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
    -moz-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
    -o-transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
    -ms-transition:opacity 0.5s linear; 
    transition:opacity 0.5s linear;
}
```

JS

```
function fadde() {
        var box = document.getElementById('box');
        box.style.opacity = (box.style.opacity == 1) ? 0 : 1;   
}
setInterval(fadde, 1000);
```

example at

https://jsfiddle.net/z54a75os/

Comment: If I used setInterval()  it flashes for me. So instead I use setTimeout().