# how to make a <div> appear in slow motion

Tags: javascript

I want the javascript code to show a div in slow motion.

```
function showDiv(divID)
{
       if(document.getElementById(divID).style.display=='none')
       {
           document.getElementById(divID).style.display='block';  
       }
}
```

Here div appears, but not in slow motion. Can anyone help ??
Thanks in advance

Dev..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need of jQuery in this atall , its just a basic I am using your function to explain how thats done.

```
   function showDiv(divID)
   {
       if(document.getElementById(divID).style.display=='none')
       {
           document.getElementById(divID).style.display='block';  
       }
}
```

What your function is doing is basically removing the whole Element from BOX Model ( the toggle of block and none removes the element totally from the BOX Model so it doesnt occupies any space or anything , this but may / may not cause some layout issues );

Now to animate it in slow motion you need a timing function.

a timing function is a simple mathematical function which gives the value of the property ( opacity in your case )  for a given time or depending on other parameters .

Other then that you also need to use properties like opacity in order to fade it (Opacity is a CSS property that defines the transparency of an element and its childrens )

So let us begin with a very basic show / hide using setTimeout Function in JS.

```
function getValue(t,dir){

  if( dir > 0){
   return 0.5*t; /* Y = mx + c  */
  }else{
   return 1-(0.5*t);
  }
  /* 
    Here the slope of line m = 0.5.
    t is the time interval.
  */
}


function animator(divID){
      if(!(this instanceof animator)) return new animator(divID); /* Ignore this */
  var Node = document.getElementById(divID),
      start = new Date.getTime(), // The initiation.
      now = 0,
      dir = 1,
      visible = true;
  function step( ){
    now = new Date.getTime();
    var val = getValue( now - start,dir)
    Node.style.opacity = val;
    if( dir > 0 && val > 1 || dir < 0 && val < 0 ){
      visible = !(visible*1);
      // Optionally here u can call the block & none 
      if( dir < 0 ) { /* Hiding  and hidden*/
        Node.style.display = 'none'; // So if were repositioning using position:relative; it will         support after hide 
      }
      /* Our animation is finished lets end the continous calls */
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(step,100); // Each step is executated in 100seconds
  }
  this.animate = function(){
    Node.style.display = 'block';
    dir *= -1;
    start = new Date.getTime();
    setTimeout(step,100);
  } 
}
```

now you can simply call the function

```
  var magician = new animator('divName');
```

then toggle its animation by

```
  magician.animate();
```

Now playing with the timing function you can create whatever possibilities you want as in

```
  return t^2 / ( 2 *3.23423 );
```

or even higher polynomial equations like

```
  return t^3+6t^2-38t+12;
```

As you can see our function is very very basic but it explains the point of how to make animations using pure js . you can later on use CSS3 module for animation and trigger those classes with javascript :-)

Or perhaps write a cross browser polyfill using CSS3 where available ( it is faster ) , and JS if not :-) hope that helps

Comment: I wrote in Form_Load...
TxtFDate.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:var magic=new animator('Hide1');magic.animate();")
but still the DIV is not showing.. Am i missing something ??

Comment: Ah dont use inline javascript ! my code wasnt inteded to work as inline javascript 


put it all in the <script> tag . that will do better.

Answer (score 4):

**Crossbrowser solution** (without jQuery) :

HTML :

```
<div id="toChange" ></div>
```

CSS :

```
#toChange
{
    background-color:red;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    opacity:0;//IE9, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, and Safari
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);//IE8 and earlier
}
```

Javascript :

```
var elem=document.getElementById("toChange");
var x=0;

function moreVisible()
{
    if(x==1)clearInterval(t);
    x+=0.05;
    elem.style.opacity=x;
    elem.style.filter="alpha(opacity="+(x*100)+")";
}
var t=setInterval(moreVisible,25);
```

Fiddle demonstration : http://jsfiddle.net/JgxW6/1/

Comment: it's nice to have a fiddle demonstration of your solution, but please post it here as well, so it doesn't get lost.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a few jQuery answers but **I wouldn't recommend jQuery if fading the div is all you want**.

Certainly jQuery makes things easier but it is a lot of overhead for a single simple functionality.

Here is someone that did it with pure JS:

[Fade in and fade out in pure javascript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript)

And a CSS3 example:

[How to trigger CSS3 fade-in effect using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126404/how-to-trigger-css3-fade-in-effect-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery  $.show('slow') for the same, if you want to do the same without using jquery then you might be required to code something to show the effect yourself, you may have a look at source of jquery's show function http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.6.2&fn=show . alternatively , you can also use fadein() for fade in effect in jquery

Comment: I am not familiar to JQuery. Is there any way to do it in Javascript ??

Comment: @Dev Actually , jquery is nothing but a framework and collection of utility functions, you just need to include jquery js file and call the functions. yes you can do it in javascript but you might end up doing a lot of code , which is alredy there ,

Comment: Oh I see.. I am adding a .JS file to my project and I have 2 div's 'Hide1' and 'Hide2' with style display:none. Now what should I do ??

Comment: you can call the jquery function on , $('DIV_ID_TO_BEHIDDEN').hide('slow') or $('DIV_ID_TO_BE_HIDDEN).FADEOUT('slow');

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it using Jquery. Here is my sample example

```
$('#divID').click(function() {
   $('#book').show('slow', function() {
// Animation complete.
  });
```

});

For details [clik here](http://api.jquery.com/show/)
Thanks.